# Count Virtual Desktops then delete more than 2

Tags: powershell, loops, do-loops, until-loop

Preface: I have not been formally trained on how to code. I have kind of winged it and done simple thing like registry entries via powershell.

I have a small script I am trying to run that will test to see how many Virtual Desktops I have running (Get-DesktopCount). I want that return to be tested and if there are 2 or more Virtual Desktops then execute the second part of the statement which is to delete any virtual desktops until there are only two virtual desktops left (Remove-Desktop)

```
$DTC = Get-DesktopCount

Do
   {
     Remove-Desktop -Desktop "Desktop 2"
   }
     Until (($DTC) -gt '2')
```

I know it has something to do with Syntax and me not being able to distinguish the different types of returns for different cmdlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three things here

The first is that when you do `$DTC = Get-DesktopCount`, what happens is you're *saving* the result of `Get-DesktopCount` as `$DTC`. No matter how many desktops you create or remove, the value stored in `$DTC` has already been set and will not update until you tell it to change.

The second is that the loop's condition seems to be backwards - you probably want to keep going `Until` there are *less* than 2 desktops (or, *`While`* there are more)

Finally, while I don't think it does any harm in this case, I don't think you want to use `Do` here - by using `Do { ... } While ( ... )` instead of `While ( ... ) { ... }` you end up running the block at least once, even if the condition is false (so you close Desktop 2 at least once, even if there are fewer than 2 desktops)

All in all, I think what you want is probably something closer to

```
While ( (Get-DesktopCount) -gt 2 ) {
    Remove-Desktop -Desktop "Desktop 2"
}
```

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense. Updating the $DTC variable was something I thought was happening during the loop automatically. Obviously I need more practice but this is a great example of While Loops without just counting up. Thank you!